# MooTools Fx.Slide for several containers on one page

Tags: javascript, mootools

Trying to add a slide effect in MooTools.

Desired functionality: click on link in `div.head` toggles `div` below it.

HTML:

```
<div class="head"><a id="v_toggle" href="#">Number One</a></div>
<div id="main">Blah blah blah...</div>
<div class="head"><a id="v_toggle" href="#">Number Two</a></div>
<div id="main">Blah blah blah...</div>
<div class="head"><a id="v_toggle" href="#">Number Three</a></div>
<div id="main">Blah blah blah...</div>
```

JS:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    var myVerticalSlide = new Fx.Slide('main');
    $('v_toggle').addEvent('click', function(event){
        event.stop();
        myVerticalSlide.toggle();
    });
});
```

Issues:

- first of all, no sliding :-(
- several elements with the same id in one page (`#v_toggle`, `#main`) --> tried to make both ids classes, didn't work either (no sliding)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S6KtS/

Comment: id attributes should be unique, it looks like you're using them like a class.  Also, Fx.Slide works on a single element, not a collection.  So you'll need to instantiate one for each thing you want to slide.   Try creating a fiddle that slides one thing successfully, then go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fx.Slide is for individual elements, not families. Besides you cannot have multiple ID's, it will break your code, it's invalid html.

Try this:

**Mootools**

```
window.addEvent('domready', function () {
    var status = [];
    var divsMain = $$('div.main');

    var toggleDivs = function(i){
        return function(){
            var nextMain = this.getParent().getNext('.main'); 
            var doIt = status[i] ? nextMain.dissolve() : nextMain.reveal();
            status[i] = !status[i];
            return false;
        }
    }
    $$('.v_toggle').each(function(el,i){
        el.addEvent('click', toggleDivs(i));
        status[i] = true;
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="head"><a class="v_toggle" href="#">Number One</a>

</div>
<div class="main">This is a lot of text in this container. I want to slide it in and out. This is an experiment with MooTools. his is a lot of text in this container. I want to slide it in and out. This is an experiment with MooTools. his is a lot of text in this container. I want to slide it in and out. This is an experiment with MooTools.</div>
<div class="head"><a class="v_toggle" href="#">Number Two</a>

</div>
<div class="main">This is a lot of text in this container. I want to slide it in and out. This is an experiment with MooTools. his is a lot of text in this container. I want to slide it in and out. This is an experiment with MooTools. his is a lot of text in this container. I want to slide it in and out. This is an experiment with MooTools.</div>
<div class="head"><a class="v_toggle" href="#">Number Three</a>

</div>
<div class="main">This is a lot of text in this container. I want to slide it in and out. This is an experiment with MooTools. his is a lot of text in this container. I want to slide it in and out. This is an experiment with MooTools. his is a lot of text in this container. I want to slide it in and out. This is an experiment with MooTools.</div>
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xngCq/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for my problem:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="head">Number One</div>
    <div class="main">Blah blah blah...</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="head">Number Two</div>
    <div class="main">Blah blah blah...</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="head">Number Three</div>
    <div class="main">Blah blah blah...</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
window.addEvent( 'domready', function(){
    $$( '.container' ).each(function(item){
        var thisSlider = new Fx.Slide( item.getElement( '.main' ), { duration: 500 } );
        thisSlider.hide();
        item.getElement( '.head' ).addEvent( 'click', function(){ thisSlider.toggle(); } );
    } );
} );
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S6KtS/3/